# Div flowing over top of screen

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to display two maps, one directly above the other, with text positioned above the first map and the second map.  Each of the maps are contained in `centered-box`. I have tried a variety of different parameters - `body { margin:0; padding:0; }`  , adding `display: absolute` to the `centered-box` class, removing `overflow:auto` but none of them work.

I understand the solution is simple - how would one position these containers in the center of the screen and not to flow off of the page?

In addition "TEXT" should be aligned to the left edge of the box, and should not overflow over the right edge of the box.

Here is the example in [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h0wL50Lv/#&togetherjs=ELbI3CB3Fz) with just the containers

```
   <style>
    body {display: flex;
  /* Specify direction where all items will */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* Center all items in this direction */
  align-items: center;}

        #map {
          width:50%;
          overflow: auto;}

        #map2 {
          width:50%;
          overflow: auto;}

        .text{
            color:#282828; font-family:Arial; font-weight:200;
        }
        .centered-box {
          left: 25%;
          top: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          width: 250px;
          height: 250px;
          align-content: center;
          border: 1px solid red;
          overflow: scroll;
        }


</style>
</head>
<body>
<style>


button {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 5px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 1010101010
}

#pause::after {
    content: 'Pause';
}

#pause.pause::after {
    content: 'Play';
}

</style>

    <div class="text">TEXT</div>
    <div class="centered-box" id="map">
    <button id="pause"></button>
</div>
    <div class="text">TEXT</div>
    <div class="centered-box" id="map2">
    <button id="pause"></button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove   `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` from your css, and there you have it.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  /* Specify direction where all items will */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* Center all items in this direction */
  align-items: center;
}

#map {
  overflow: auto;
}
#map2 {
  overflow: auto;
}
.text{
  color:#282828; 
  font-family:Arial; 
  font-weight:200;
}
.centered-box {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  align-content: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: scroll;
}

button {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 5px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 1010101010
}

#pause::after {
    content: 'Pause';
}

#pause.pause::after {
    content: 'Play';
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div>
      <p class="text">TEXT</p>
      <div class="centered-box" id="map2">
        <button id="pause"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="text">TEXT</p>
      <div class="centered-box" id="map2">
        <button id="pause"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you need a tweak, or I have misunderstood what you need, please let me know :) I have a feeling like your buttons are not behaving the way you would want them to, as they are fixed onto a page. (Try reducing width and height of screen, and scrolling)

Comment: Yes this works! Thank you, though TEXT should be aligned to the left edge of the box, and should not overflow over the right edge of the box - does that make sense?

Comment: @the_darkside Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

was the problem. As soon as you remove it everything aligns correctly in the centre. If you don't want it centre aligned remove:

```
 align-items: center;
```

from the body tag.

Here is an amended JS Fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/h0wL50Lv/2/